# How errors should be treated implementing fmt::Display?

Tags: error-handling, rust

I wonder how to convert properly interim errors of other types than `fmt::Error` which may arise on the track of `fn fmt`, to the `fmt::Error` type?

Let's say:

```
use std::fmt;
use serde::{Serialize, Deserialize};

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct MyStruct {
    x: i32
}

impl fmt::Display for MyStruct {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        write!(f, "{}", serde_json::to_string(&self).map_err(|e| /*???*/)?)
    }
}
```

As shown in the example above, I wonder how should I convert, for instance, `serde_json::Error` to `fmt::Error` to comply with the returned `fmt::Result` trait.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`fmt::Error` has no fields. It's simply an indicator value that "does not support transmission of an error other than that an error occurred" ([docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/struct.Error.html)). So, if you're fine with just returning an error with no other message, then map the error to `fmt::Error`:

```rust
foo.map_err(|_| fmt::Error)
```

Comment: And in this case, I suppose, there is even no way to specify, since according to the trait the returned type is not supposed to be `dyn` or even a `trait`. So there is exactly no way to do it, is it?

Comment: Yes, there's no way to convey the error in the return value. From the docs: "Any extra information must be arranged to be transmitted through some other means."